# unable to resolve the error for importing keys in selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python and I am writing a code for fb automation using selenium webdriver. I wrote the following command:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1frb').send_keys(keys.ENTER)
```

and also included the library:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

it shows the following error:

```
NameError: name 'keys' is not defined
```

Why am I getting this error? What changes can I make to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Python is a case-sensitive programming language, so you should use Keys.ENTER with capital K.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't defined variable called keys